# MongoDB : Remove last two characters from String

Tags: mongodb, substring, substr

How to remove the last two characters of String in MongoDB?

I have tried below solution but it did not work.

```
   $substr: [ "$document.field", 0, { $strLenCP: "$document.field" } - 2 ]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) or [$subrtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/index.html) to evaluate the length of a new string:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            newStr: {
                $substr: [ "$document.field", 0, { $add: [ { $strLenCP: "$document.field" }, -2 ] } ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_k7ERifRPFZ)