# pymongo update all documents in collection for field with it's substring value

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

```
{'some': 'abcdefg', 'some2': 'hijklmn'}
```

Desired output

```
{'some': 'abc', 'some2': 'hij'}
```

in other words substring [:3]

How can I achieve this with pymongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use updatemany with an aggregation : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

```
update_pipe =   [
                      { "$set":
                              { "some":
                                      { "$substr":  ['$some', 0,3]}
                              },
                      },
                       
                      { "$set":
                              { "some2":
                                      { "$substr":  ['$some2', 0,3]}
                              },
                      }
                  ]
collection.update_many({}, update_pipe)
```

Comment: can negative indexes can be used as in python? for example 0, -14?

Comment: using a negative value for the length argument returns the rest of the string from the starting index, so in this case, the whole string.

Comment: So the answer is no, what I then need is to loop over documents, and to calculate right index, any help?

Comment: Depends on what you need, you can use the length of the string and $add/$subtract to get the right index.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537076/mongodb-remove-last-two-characters-from-string